# Count duplicates of own structure in list

Tags: c#

```
Dictionary<string, int> personListCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var person in personList) {
    if (!personListCount.ContainsKey(person.ID)) {
        personListCount.Add(person.ID, 1);
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        personListCount.TryGetValue(person.ID, out count);
        personListCount.Remove(person.ID);
        personListCount.Add(person.ID, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID     Count
1      7
2      5
```

Each person has `ID` and `Name`, how can I store also `Name`?

Expected output:

```
ID     Name     Count
1      John     7
2      Andrew   5
```

Comment: Create a person object with all the properties you want to store and create a dictionary... See @Sergii Bidnyi 's answer below

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The title is not exactly clear, since there is no list in the sample code. But it seems like you need to create a `class Person` to contain the `Id` and `Name` properties.

Answer (score 1):

There plenty of ways to do what you want, for example, to use a value type as a key

```
public struct Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string {get;set;}
}
Dictionary<Person, int> personListCount = new Dictionary<Person, int>();
//the rest of your code
```

Comment: But `ContainsKey` would be applied for whole struct, wouldn't be? How can I apply it just for `ID`?

Comment: dont compare on the ID compare on the person as such  - if(!personListCount.ContainsKey(person))

Comment: You'll need to either specify the property(ies) for comparison or implement equals, since the default comparison is a reference comparison.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a class to represent a person:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can have a list of people:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person(1, "John"),
    new Person(1, "John"),
    new Person(1, "John"),
    new Person(2, "Andrew"),
    new Person(2, "Andrew"),
};
```

And we can use the `GroupBy` method in the `System.Linq` namespace to group them by the `Id` property:

```
var peopleGroups = people.GroupBy(p => p.Id);
```

Finally, we can output the count of people in each group:

```
Console.WriteLine("ID".PadRight(5) + "Name".PadRight(10) + "Count");
foreach (var peopleGroup in peopleGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(peopleGroup.Key.ToString().PadRight(5) +
                      peopleGroup.First().Name.PadRight(10) + 
                      peopleGroup.Count());
}
```

**Output**

[image]